# User.IsInRole() takes a very long time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently have the following code in an `ASP.Net Core 1.0` application:

```
_logger.LogInformation($"Starting at {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
user.IsInRole(AccessRoles.GetDomainRole(Startup.Configuration["Roles:DataEntryAll"]));
_logger.LogInformation($"Stopping at {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

This outputs the following:

```
<Namespace>.Authorization.Requirements.DataEntryHandler: Information: Starting at 0
<Namespace>.Authorization.Requirements.DataEntryHandler: Information: Stopping at 42006
```

Does anyone know why this would be taking such a long time, and are there any way to improve its speed?

It is running on my development machine which is connected to our local domain controller (All via gigabit lan). There are only around 10 users on the local domain, and not many roles/groups.

**EDIT**

I should note, the `AccessRoles.GetDomainRole(...)` just prepends the domain to the role (IE: Nothing that will take time):

```
public static string GetDomainRole(string role)
{
    return $"{Startup.Configuration["Domain:Name"]}\\{role}";
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's `IsInRole`? Looks like there's something else happening there too...

Comment: Is the DC responding with the expected answer? My first thought was that your code is not actually able to connect to the DC and so the long delay is your code waiting for the connection to time out.

Comment: @VinceHorst no, it works perfectly fine, just takes a long time. If it helps, my primary DNS is set to the domain controller.

Comment: @JosephGarrone sorry, I don't have any other ideas. It could be simply that ASP.NET Core 1.0 is buggy - it was released less than a month ago. Good luck and best wishes.